# Open Play Store on component load in Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, mobile-browser

I want to open [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) on `ngOnInit`.
I have tried every combination but host name is added automatically.

myComponent.ts

```
var url1 = 'market.android.com/details?id=com.test&referrer=' + sponser;
window.open(url1, '_blank') //try1
  $.get(url1, function () { /!*callback*!/
  }); //try2

const link = document.createElement('a');
link.target = '_top';
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden');
link.click();//try3
```

But none of them are working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no typo error @BenM

Comment: Is it fine now?The question was for something else though.But thanks :)